# auth0 React Native hangs on auth0.webAuth.authorize()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, auth0

I use the Auth0 Universal login in my React Native app, and up until today it's worked fine. All of a sudden the app is hanging on `auth0.webAuth.authorize()`. When I call `auth0.webAuth.authorize()`, nothing happens and there are no associated error messages. Has anyone run into this or have suggestions on how to approach troubleshooting it?

Comment: Are you getting a timeout? Is it still occurring today?